# JS: how to algorithmically highlight a diamond-shaped selection of x/y coordinates?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, tiles

If given an array of arrays creating an n x n map of tiles, is there a way to loop through an algorithm that would highlight tiles which form a diamond shape? (the key problem is not to hardcode it, so it could work for any sized map)

For example: if the map was 5x5 tiles like so:

```
XXXXX  
XXXXX  
XXXXX  
XXXXX  
XXXXX
```

How could an algorithm highlight a diamond shape like so:

```
XXOXX  
XOOOX  
OOOOO  
XOOOX  
XXOXX
```

Comment: Do you need an algorithm which simply produces an nxn array of diamonds, flagged, or are you struggling with the "highlight" step, for which you given no real description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[[Working example](http://jsbin.com/iloxa3/)]**

```
function diamond(arr) {
  var len = arr.length;
  var mid = Math.floor(len / 2);
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var d = Math.abs(i - mid);
    for (var j = d; j < len - d; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = arr[i][j] = 1;
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

*Please note that you haven't defined the expected behavior for even numbers*

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old topic but I think I just figured out the best method.

If cX,cY is the center of the diamond and r is the "radius" (not the diameter) use this condition in your loop:

```
if (Math.abs(x-cX)+Math.abs(y-cY)<r)
    arr[x][y] = 1;
```

so cX=2, cY=2, r=3 would draw

```
0,0,1,0,0
0,1,1,1,0
1,1,1,1,1
0,1,1,1,0
0,0,1,0,0
```

Now you can set cX and cY to your mouse position and increase/descrease the diamond size using r.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, is there a way to cut a hole in the middle of the diamond? Such as adding an offset param?

Comment: Since I haven't gotten a response I've figured it out and put the code into a JSFiddle. Feel free to play around with it here http://jsfiddle.net/truefreestyle/Suww8/

Answer (score 1):

```
function diamond(arr) {

var m = Math.floor(arr.length / 2); // mid
var i = 0;
for (; i < arr.length / 2; i ++) {
  for (var j = 0; j <= i; j ++) {
    for (var k = 0; k <= j; k ++) {
      arr[i][m + k] = arr[i][m - k] = 1;
    }
  }
}

for (; i < arr.length; i ++) {
  for (var j = arr.length - 1 - i; j >= 0; j --) {
    for (var k = 0; k <= j; k ++) {
      arr[i][m + k] = arr[i][m - k] = 1;
    }
  }
}

return arr;

}
```

>> Example: (9x9 array)

```
diamond((function(n) { var a = []; for (var i = 0; i < n; i ++) { a[i] = []; for (var j = 0; j < n; j ++) { a[i][j] = 0; } }; return a;})(9)).join('\n');
```

=> Output:

```
0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0
0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0
0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
```