# JS: given a point in a 2d array and a distance, which coordinates are travelable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d, tiles

Given a 2D array of any size like so:

```
var board = [
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
];
```

...and a given [y][x] point in that array, such as:

```
board[3][4]
```

...and a given number of spaces it can travel (up/down/left/right, *not* diagonally), like:

```
var distance = 3;
```

...how would a function loop through the 2D array and create a list of only those **coordinates** that may be traveled?

(Here's a visual example of the given coordinate (*) in the array, and the surrounding travelable coordinates.)

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0
0 0 3 2 3 0 0 0
0 3 2 1 2 3 0 0
3 2 1 * 1 2 3 0
0 3 2 1 2 3 0 0
0 0 3 2 3 0 0 0
0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0
```

Reference: [JS: how to algorithmically highlight a diamond-shaped selection of x/y coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952142/js-how-to-algorithmically-highlight-a-diamond-shaped-selection-of-x-y-coordinate) 
(I asked this question before, but I can't understand how to input a coordinate and receive a list of coordinates)

Comment: Depends greatly on the specifics: can the 'traveler' move diagonally? Can there be 'walls' on the board (for example, a cell with a '1' on it can't be traversable?

Comment: No direct diagonal movement; a unit must travel over and up (2 movements) to reach a diagonal tile. There can be walls, but I was thinking of executing this "distance diamond" function first to get all the possible nearby travelable tiles, and provide a hover effect to all those which are not obstacles, then use a pathfinding function to move to the coordinate clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest solution I could think of, it involves working from top to bottom and left to right, iterating over *only the co-ordinates that are permissible moves* so it should be pretty fast:

```
function getPossibleMoves(x, y) {
    var r, c, cMax, 
        distance = 3,
        rows = board.length,
        cols = board[0].length, 
        rMax = Math.min(y + distance + 1, rows),
        ret  = [],
        yOff;

    // Start at the first row with a permissible move
    for (r = Math.max(y - distance, 0); r < rMax; r++) {
        yOff = Math.abs(r - y);

        // Work out where we should stop looping for this row
        cMax = Math.min(x + distance - yOff + 1, cols);

        // Start at the first column with a permissible move
        for (c = Math.max(x - distance + yOff, 0); c < cMax; c++) {
            // If it's not the current position, add it to the result
            if (x != c || y != r)
                ret.push([c, r]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

To give you a better idea, I threw together a demo that allows you to adjust all the different variables, e.g. board size, distance, etc.

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/fWDHy/2/**

Comment: This makes me want to cry with joy. It's perfect! You've saved my life, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over all coordinates (or a subset `x-d,y-d` ... `x+d,y+d` if the area is big).

For each field of those, calculate the distance - in your case as `dx - dy` - and whenever you find a point with the distance > 0, do anything you want with it. Otherwise, ignore it. That's it!

Compared to a flood-fill approach, you get simple code and no overhead of additinal lookup tables.

Comment: You should limit the iteration by +-d around the origin, for efficiency purposes.

Comment: Is there a function like this somewhere that you could point me to?

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion along with a list/hash of visited links. Take a step, reduce your ability to travel by one and pass along the list of what you've seen. Add your current location to the list of visited spots. Go in each direction one step (using recursion), passing along a 'steps left' value that is one less than you were given.

Here's an answer that [almost works](http://jsfiddle.net/eUQRR/); the only problem is that it never re-visits a cell even if the long way was used to get there. You could overcome this either via a [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or by detecting if the visited cell was reached via more steps than you are about to take to get there.

Comment: That's a valid algorithm for the general case, but since the world described in the problem consists only of a 2D cartesian grid, only two for-loops are necessary.  I think he is really asking how to return a list of coordinates, however.

Comment: Basically a flood-fill with additional limit? Kind of heavy solution for such a simple problem, I suppose.

Comment: @Kos Right you are; not sure why I went down the recursion path :)